# Alternative to Windows Performance Monitor

Tags: windows, monitoring, performance-analysis

I am looking for a program that can identify file IO and CPU usage to cross-reference to windows performance monitor. I would like to be able to attach the program to an executable file and monitor it's average IO write speed in Mb/s. It should be able to log the values it measures in order to graph or store as a spreadsheet.

Comment: We will need much more information to give good recommendations here – asking for "a tool like X" is never giving enough details, even if linked. You should always list your requirements explicitly. Please see [How to ask for an alternative to some software](//softwarerecs.meta.stackexchange.com/q/48/185) and the questions linked to it for details.

Comment: Yeah, well... Probably Izzy is right. If you manage to specify more precisely what you need, I'm likely gonna have an answer for you. Izzy was just 20 seconds too fast for me posting an answer

Comment: Is this question sufficient now?